# What the function of TagGroupReleaseSeeds

Tags: dm-script

In the manual of DM script, it said the function of TagGroupReleaseSeeds is "Releases the seeds returned by 'TagGroupGetSeeds'." But I can't catch the meaning. Could anyone give me more explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that these commands are of much use to you.

Their purpose is to check the "dirty" state of a TagGroup (i.e. whether it changed since some other point in time.)
Essentially, a TagGroup has an internal "counter" of changes which is increased whenever it is changed. You can use it like this:

```c
ClearResults()
taggroup testTG = NewTagGroup()
Result("Seeds of Taggroup:\n")
Result( testTG.TagGroupGetSeeds() +"\n")
Result( testTG.TagGroupGetSeeds() +"\n")
testTG.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber("Dummy",-100)
Result( testTG.TagGroupGetSeeds() +"\n")
testTG.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber("Dummy",100)
Result( testTG.TagGroupGetSeeds() +"\n")
testTG.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber("Dummy2",-100)
Result( testTG.TagGroupGetSeeds() +"\n")
testTG.TagGroupMarkAsChanged()
Result( testTG.TagGroupGetSeeds() +"\n")

Result("\n Remember Tag state...") 
number seeds = testTG.TagGroupGetSeeds()
testTG.TagGroupSetTagAsString("str","dummy")

if ( testTG.TagGroupHasChangedSince(seeds) )
    Result("\n Tag was changed since remembered state...")
```